# Complex functions from python to pyspark - EDIT: concatenation problem (I think)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to transform a pandas function over two dataframes to a pyspark function.

In particular, I have a dataframe of Keys and functions as strings, namely:

```
> mv

| Keys |       Formula        | label |
---------------------------------------
| key1 | 'val1 + val2 - val3' | name1 |
| key2 | 'val3 + val4'        | name2 |
| key3 | 'val1 - val4'        | name3 |
```

and a dataframe df:

```
> df

| Keys | Datetime | names | values |
------------------------------------
| key1 | tmstmp1  | val1  |  0.3   |
| key1 | tmstmp1  | val2  |  0.4   |
| key1 | tmstmp1  | val3  |  0.2   |
| key1 | tmstmp1  | val4  |  1.2   |
| key1 | tmstmp2  | val1  |  0.5   |
| key2 | tmstmp1  | val1  |  1.1   |
| key2 | tmstmp2  | val3  |  1.0   |
| key2 | tmstmp1  | val3  |  1.3   |
```

and so on.

I've created two functions that read the code, evaluate the string ok the measure expression, and return a list of pandas.DataFrame that in the end I concat.

```
def evaluate_vm(x, regex):
    m = re.findall(regex, x)
    to_replace = ['#[' + i + ']' for i in m]
    replaces = [i.split(', ') for i in m]
    replacement = ["df.loc[(df.Keys == %s) & (df.names == %s), ['Datetime', 'values']].dropna().set_index('Datetime')"%tuple(i) for i in replaces]
    for i in range(len(to_replace)):
        x = x.replace(to_replace[i], replacement[i])
    return eval(x)


def _mv_(X):
    formula = evaluate_vm(X.Formula)
    formula['Keys'] = X.Keys
    formula.reset_index(inplace = True)
    formula.rename_axis({'Formula': 'Values'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)
    return formula[['Keys', 'Datetime', 'names', 'Values']]
```

After that my code is

```
res = pd.concat([_mv_(mv.loc[i]) for i in mv.index])
```

and res is what I need to obtain.

NOTE: I've slightly modified the functions and inputs in order to make it understandable: anyway, I don't think the problem lies here.

Here's the thing. I'm trying to transform this stuff in pyspark.

This is the code I wrote this far.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType, StructType, StructField

EvaluateVM = pandas_udf(lambda x: _mv_(x),\
                        functionType = PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP, \
                        returnType = StructType([StructField("Keys", StringType(), False),
                                                 StructField("Datetime", TimestampType(), False),\
                                                 StructField("names", StringType(), False),\
                                                 StructField("Values", FloatType(), False)])
                       )

res = EvaluateVM(struct([mv[i] for i in mv.columns]))
```

That is "almost" working: when I print res here's the result.

```
> res
Column<<lambda>(named_struct(Keys, Keys, Formula, Formula))>
```

And I can't see inside res: I think it created something like a python iterable, but I would like to have the same result I get in pandas.

What should I do? Did I get it all wrong?

EDIT: I think the problem might be in the fact that in pandas I create a list of dataframes that I concatenate after evaluating them, in pyspark I use a sort of `apply(_mv_, axis = 1)`: this kind of syntax gave me error even in pandas (`cannot concatenate dataframe of dimension 192 into one of size 5`, something like that), and my workaround was the `pandas.concat([…])`. I don't know if this works in pyspark too, or if there's some way to avoid this.

EDIT 2: Sorry, I didn't write the expected output:

```
| Keys | Datetime | label |     values      |
---------------------------------------------
| key1 | tmstmp1  | name1 | 0.3 + 0.4 - 0.2 |
| key1 | tmstmp1  | name2 |    0.2 + 1.2    |
```

and so on. The values column should contain the numeric result, here I wrote the operands in order to let you understand.

Comment: Have you tried `res.show(10)` ?

Comment: @ChrisA yes, it returns `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Comment: Please post the expected output. That would get a clear idea.

Comment: @JimTodd updated, ty